# Is there a vector product where each component is the product of the respective component of each multiplicand?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a vector-multiplication defined as follows:

$$
v * w = (v_1,...,v_n)*(u_1,...,u_n)=(v_1u_1,...,v_nu_n).
$$

Comment: This is the Hadamard product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the "Hadamard product". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_%28matrices%29